# add excel formula if/or statement to vba code

Tags: excel, vba

I have this vba code that create a list from another list.
What I would like is to add this formula on every row of my new list on column E :

I want to add the formula to this vba code:

```
Sub m()
Dim c As Range
ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
Range("A:E").Delete
For Each c In Sheets("Feuil1").Range("b2:b300")
    If c.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = vbYellow Then
        Sheets("Feuil3").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).EntireRow.Value = c.EntireRow.Value
    End If
Next c
End Sub
```

I just dont know how to link them.. thank you

Comment: `Sheets("Feuil3").Range("E2:E300").Formula = "=IF(OR(D2=""TARM01"",D2 = ""BOUM34"",D2=""LESB01""), ""true"",""false"")"`

Comment: It work great but it should stop generating the formula at the end of my new list. In this case right now, the formula is looping forever ... @ScottCraner

Comment: that line should not be in the loop.  It should be the last line before the `End Sub`

Comment: sorry, i didnt meant looping forever, I wanted to say it goes from E2:E300 even when the new list is only 20 rows long. I would like to match the formula with how many rows are generated in the new list by the loop.

Comment: Then you will need to find the end of the data.  See: 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba for examples on how to do that.  Then you would just do something like: `Sheets("Feuil3").Range("E2:E" & lastrow).Formula =...`

Comment: Can't I just say something like "if D cell <> "" then... run the formula" ?

Comment: sure, but make sure you change the row reference in the formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Formula to Range

- The implementation of a (one-cell) range variable (`dCell`) makes the code more readable and will make it easy to determine the last row for the formula.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub m()
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
    Range("A:E").Delete
    Dim dCell As Range
    Set dCell = Sheets("Feuil3").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Sheets("Feuil1").Range("B2:B300").Cells
        If c.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = vbYellow Then
            dCell.EntireRow.Value = c.EntireRow.Value
            Set dCell = dCell.Offset(1)
        End If
    Next c
    Sheets("Feuil3").Range("E2:E" & dCell.Row - 1).Formula = "=IF(OR(D2" _
        & "=""TARM01"",D2=""BOUM34"",D2=""LESB01""),""true"",""false"")"
End Sub
```